# Retry stream in akka on failure of any stage in flow

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream, retry-logic

I am using akka stream to process my data. In which I have 1 Source which consists of element UUID.

The flow is as follows :

1. is fetching the Element from some third party HTTP service which returns complete Element with its properties.
2. Then I retrieve required data from that element and convert it to object that my application understands.
3. Then i write the data from that object to DB.
4. Finally, I update the DB with status of all the elements in the stream.

Now I want to add retry mechanism to this flow so that if any of the stages in flow fails it should retry the stage for some no of times say 3 and if after that it fails then the only failure of the stream should happen. For example, if there are some issues with third-party service like HTTP 504 error then most of the time after retrying this element success. So is there any way in akka to achieve this.

Currently, I am maintaining 1 list to store all the failed element ids like below.

Code :

```
List<UUID> failedId = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
Source.from(elementIdToProcess).map(f -> {
            failedId.add(f);
            return f;
        }).via(featureFlow()).via(filterNullFeaturesFlow())
            .via(mapToFeatureFlow()).via(setFeaturesAdditionalInfo())
            .runForeach(features -> {
                features.parallelStream().forEach(feature -> {
                    try {
                        featureCommitter.save(feature);
                        failedId.remove(UUID.fromString(feature.getFeatureId()));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                });
            }, materializer);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can retry like this

```
source.recoverWithRetries(attempts = 2, {
  case _: RuntimeException ⇒ source
})
```

Or you can have a back off strategy using either `RestartSource`, `RestartSink` or `RestartFlow`.
All of this is documented in the [Akka docs](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-error.html#recover-with-retries)

Comment: Simon recoverWithRetries, RestartFlow doesn't match my use case. As in recoverWithRetries i need to provide one more stream for execution which i don't want to i want to continue my current stream with retrying the failed elements. And in case of RestartFlow it skips the element on which exception occurred which i don't want to.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and solved it with Future feature named [retry](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/futures.html#retry)

Base on your code I would implemente it this way:

```java
  @BeforeClass
  public static void setUpClass() {
      system = ActorSystem.create();
      mat = ActorMaterializer.create(system);
  }

  @AfterClass
  public static void tearDown() {
      TestKit.shutdownActorSystem(system);
      system = null;
  }

  @Test
  public void shouldRetryArbitraryNumberOfTimes() {
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(featureCommitter).process(anyString(), anyString(), anyString());
    TestSubscriber.Probe<Message> probe = getJmsSource().runWith(TestSink.probe(system), mat);
    Throwable throwable = probe.request(1).expectError();
    verify(featureCommitter, timeout(5000).times(4)).save(any(Feature.class));
  }

  private Source<Feature> getJmsSource() {
    List<UUID> failedId = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
      return Source.from(elementIdToProcess)
              .via(featureFlow())
              .via(filterNullFeaturesFlow())
              .via(mapToFeatureFlow())
              .via(setFeaturesAdditionalInfo())
              .mapAsync(1, features -> {
                      features.parallelStream().forEach(feature -> retry(getCompletionStageCallable(feature),
                                                                         3, 
                                                                         Duration.ofMillis(200),
                                                                         system.scheduler(),
                                                                         system.dispatcher());
                  });
  }

  private Callable<CompletionStage<Feature>> getCompletionStageCallable(Feature feature) {
    () -> {
      return return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
          try {
              featureCommitter.save(feature);
          } catch (Exception e) {
              throw new RuntimeException(e);
          }
          return feature;
      }
  }
```

The main thing to take into account here is that we are not handling the retry as part of the stream but rather as a way to handle the future.
As you can see I moved the saving out of the Sink and into a `mapAsync` in which I set the parallelism to 1. This is so that I can use a `TestSubscriber.Probe` to validate the stream behavior.

I hope this helps.

Regards

Comment: thank you for the solution, but I implemented it in some other way which doesn't need Akka stream retry.

Comment: @Ajinkya could you elaborate on your solution pls?

Comment: i used try catch block inside Akka pipeline and if the call fails used the counter to keep on calling the method again and again. If the counter reaches 0 then i am failing the pipeline.